# When I click on "Brightness And Lock" icon, system settings disappears

Tags: 12.10

I did fix the appearances but the brightness and lock is now broken. After installing gnome classic and gnome. I then uninstall gnome classic and gnome but it was still broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you're problem is with the Icon then by changing the system theme to its default you can reset the icon. To do that I can suggest you Ubuntu tweak tool.Open your terminal and type as

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/0.8.x/0.8.5/+download/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.5-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ubuntu-tweak_0.8.5-1_all.deb
```

Then open your unity dash and there type as Ubuntu tweak. Then in Ubuntu tweak reset your system theme to its defaults.

[image]